# Ajax code for form submission still refreshes page

Tags: ajax

This is my ajax code.. I don't know what im doing wrong. The problem is even if I have this code, the page still refreshes after the form is submitted.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.regForm').submit(function(event) {

    var formData = {
        'fname' : $('input[fname=fname]').val(),
        'midname' : $('input[midname=midname]').val(),
        'lname' : $('input[lname=lname]').val(),
        'uname' : $('input[uname=uname]').val(),
        'pass' : $('input[pass=pass]').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'registeruser.php',
        data: formData,
        datatype: 'json',
        encode: true
    })

    .done(function(data) {
        alert('registerd successfully');
    });

    event.preventDefault();
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it...

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'registeruser.php',
  data: formData,
  datatype: 'json',
  encode: true,
success: function(data){
alert('registerd successfully');
}
});



event.preventDefault();
```